# sum no suppressed value in crystal report

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

I want to exclude suppressed value in total, below is my code in crystal report:

Here's part of my data

```
   staffid  payid   hrswrkd    unitid  distamnt

      2      120       40        hrs     2000
    **2**  **120**   **40**    **hrs**   1000
      2      121       10        hrs      500
    **2**  **121     **10**    **hrs**    300
```

Total hours       100      hrs     3800

I would like to suppress the value that are in **, but keeping the values that is not bold. Also the total hours should only be `50 hours` instead of `100 hours`. Can anyone help me on this?

This code is used in `Page header`:

```
whileprintingrecords;
global numbervar nTotal:=0;
```

This is used in `Details`:

```
whileprintingrecords;
global numbervar nTotal:=nTotal+({table.hrswrkd});
```

This is used in `Page footer`:

```
whileprintingrecords;
global numbervar nTotal;
```

Comment: And what is the record suppression logic?

Comment: First question why are you including in the calculation the value when not required and supressing again?

Comment: i just want to sum that value which are not suppressed, above query include suppressed value also

Comment: In Details formula, sum only these values, which are visible. This approach is generally not nice, but easiest for you to implement.

Comment: please tell me how can i do that

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide us with the suppression logic. But basically you are going to duplicate the suppression logic within the Details section. Check if the suppressions logic is false (i.e. it will be shown) and then add it to the total

Details Section:

```
whileprintingrecords;
if Not(supression logic) then
     global numbervar nTotal:=nTotal+({table.hrswrkd});
```

Comment: thanks for the advice, i am using given code but it exclude the first entry in the report